# Erro Cannot invoke initialize for type "CLLocationCordinate2D" with an argument list of type "latitude : String"

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Estou desenvolvendo um app que captura a localização do usuario com a *Core Location* e salva em uma arquivo.

Agora tenho um mapview e preciso exibir esta localização no mapa (esta localizacao vem do arquivo).

Estou usando este código:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // 1
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
      latitude: 51.50007773,
      longitude: -0.1246402
    )
    // 2
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    //3   
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = location
    annotation.title = "Big Ben"
    annotation.subtitle = "London"
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Porem quando coloco no lugar de latitude e longitude onde ele pede, ele da erro pois estou passando uma variável.

código completo :

```
class mapViewController : UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
// RECupera Arquivo
func getFilepath() -> String
{
    let userDomainPaths: NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

    let filepath: String = userDomainPaths.objectAtIndex(0) as! String

    return "\(filepath)/afMyLocation.plist"
}

//FIM
//Abre Posicao 



// FIM

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("LOG : Map carregado com sucesso")
    //Verifica arquivo


    let FLatitude : Double?
    let FLongitude : Double?

    let filepathAux: String = self.getFilepath()
    if(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(filepathAux) == true) {
        print("Verificou se existe arquivo - crioui cordenadas")
        let array: NSArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filepathAux)!
        let FLatitude : String?
        let FLongitude : String?
        FLatitude = (array.objectAtIndex(0) as? String)!
        FLongitude = (array.objectAtIndex(1) as? String)!
                } else {
        print("Erro ao recuperar posicao")
        //exibe alerta
    }

    //FIM
    //EXIBE PONTO NO MAPA
        // 1

    //let latitude = (FLatitude as NSString).doubleValue
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: 51.50007773,
            longitude: -0.1246402
        )
        // 2
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        //3
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = location
        annotation.title = "Big Ben"
        annotation.subtitle = "London"
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
    }


    //let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 21.282778, longitude: -157.829444)
    // *** Carega o point - Augusto Furlan ***

    //let lat :Double = NSString(string: FLatitude).floatValue
            // FIM
```

Alguém saberia a solução?

Comment: Qual erro que aparece?

Comment: Cannot invoke initialize for type "CLLocationCordinate2D" with an argument list of type "(latitude : String ... Sabe como pode arrumar ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que acontece é que você está passando uma **String** sendo que os valores esperados nos parâmetros `latitude` e `longitude` é um **double**.

Neste caso, você precisa converter estas variáveis primeiro, por exemplo:

```
let latitude = (strLat as NSString).doubleValue
let longitude = (strLng as NSString).doubleValue
```

Onde `strLat` e `strLng` são as variáveis que você está recebendo.

---

Com seu código mais completo, consegui compreender um pouco mais o seu problema. Em alguns pontos há um certo equivoco, como por exemplo, você declara as variáveis `FLatitude` e `FLongitude` duas vezes. Uma fora e outra dentro da sua condição.

Para corrigir isto, segue um trecho de código como minha sugestão:

```
var fLatitude: Double = 0.0
var fLongitude: Double = 0.0

let filepathAux: String = getFilepath()

if (NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(filepathAux)) {
    let array: NSArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filepathAux)!

    fLatitude = (array.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSString).doubleValue
    fLongitude = (array.objectAtIndex(1) as! NSString).doubleValue
} else {
    print("Erro ao recuperar posicao")
}

let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
    latitude: fLatitude,
    longitude: fLongitude
)
```

Comment: Amigo eu testei isso, ele me retorna outro erro : Double? is not convertible to NSString. Saberia a solução ?

Comment: Tem algo que não está batendo com sua pergunta ou precisa nos contextualizar melhor. No primeiro erro, está indicando que a variável que você está passando para o parâmetro `latitude` é uma *String*, e agora parece ser um *Double*, o que na primeira situação não iria gerar o primeiro erro.

Comment: Bom, como pode estar ocorrendo erro de comunicação, estou enviando todo o código no post abaixo.

Comment: Augusto, agora consegui compreender melhor o problema. Editei minha resposta.

Comment: muito obrigado faz 2 dias que estava tentando, muito obrigadooooo . Aproveitando deixo te fazer uma pergunta : Antes o mapa aparecia mais ampliado, como posso fazer Para voltar isso ? Assim o usuário não tem que ficar dando zoom sempre

Comment: A região do mapa pode ser definida na classe `MKCoordinateSpanMake`, que no seu caso está com **0.05** nos dois parâmetros. Estes valores definidos como a distância norte-sul e leste-oeste em graus. Você pode, por exemplo, experimentar colocar um valor maior, como **3.0** para aparecer mais distante.

Comment: Ok deu certo... Obrigadoo